# I have a AS3 Flash File with Dynamic XML content and I need it to restart when finished

Tags: actionscript-3, loops, actionscript, flash

My code loads in 3 random images and I'm not using the timeline. I need to restart the swf after a certain amount of time so the movie can reload new images and replay the movie. As it stands it won't loop.

```
import com.greensock.*;
import com.greensock.easing.*


box1.back.rotationY = -90;
box1.back.alpha=0;



var flipSpeed:Number = .25; 



var tl:TimelineMax = new TimelineMax({delay:2});

tl.append(TweenMax.to(box1.front, flipSpeed, {rotationY:90, visible:false, ease:Linear.easeNone}))
tl.append(TweenMax.to(box1.back, 0, {alpha:1, immediateRender:false}))
tl.append(TweenMax.to(box1.back, flipSpeed, {rotationY:0, ease:Linear.easeNone}))

var tb:TimelineMax = new TimelineMax({delay:4});

box2.back2.rotationY = -90;
box2.back2.alpha=0;


tb.append(TweenMax.to(box2.front2, flipSpeed, {rotationY:90, visible:false, ease:Linear.easeNone}))
tb.append(TweenMax.to(box2.back2, 0, {alpha:1, immediateRender:false}))
tb.append(TweenMax.to(box2.back2, flipSpeed, {rotationY:0, ease:Linear.easeNone}))

var ins:TimelineMax = new TimelineMax({delay:6});

box3.back3.rotationY = -90;
box3.back3.alpha=0;

ins.append(TweenMax.to(box3.front3, flipSpeed, {rotationY:90, visible:false, ease:Linear.easeNone}))
ins.append(TweenMax.to(box3.back3, 0, {alpha:1, immediateRender:false}))
ins.append(TweenMax.to(box3.back3, flipSpeed, {rotationY:0, ease:Linear.easeNone}))

var per:TimelineMax = new TimelineMax({delay:7});

person.back_person.rotationY = -90;
person.back_person.alpha=0;

per.append(TweenMax.to(person.front_person, flipSpeed, {rotationY:90, visible:false, ease:Linear.easeNone}))
per.append(TweenMax.to(person.back_person, 0, {alpha:1, immediateRender:false}))
per.append(TweenMax.to(person.back_person, flipSpeed, {rotationY:0, ease:Linear.easeNone}));
```

-- I also have content in movieclips which loads in images from an XML document but this is what I have on my main actions layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for instance, you can try this approach:

1. wrap your code into a function
2. recall itself after a certain amount of time
3. don’t forget to call the function once at startup

example:

```
import flash.utils.*;    // required for setTimeout

function doStuff() {
    …
    setTimeout(doStuff, 8000);
}

doStuff();
```

Comment: this works great! you are the man! The only issue I'm having is once the function is called and the swf restarts certain text won't show, any idea why?

Comment: No worries @Mario I figured it out, it was the way I was letting the text leave the function. I just had to add tb.append(TweenMax.to(box2.front2, flipSpeed, {rotationY:0, visible:true, ease:Linear.easeNone}))